# ionic 5 ,Push Notifications not working on Android 12 & Android 13 |

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, cordova-plugins, ionic5

In ionic 5 (Cordova), phonegap-plugin-push not supporting for Push Notification Receiving.
Android version 12 and Greater versions as well as IOS

Answer (score 0):

If ionic 5 (Cordova), phonegap-plugin-push is not supporting for Push Notification Receiving in Android version 12 and Greater versions as well as IOS do the following:

**Step 1:** You have to be sure the plugin is installed correctly by runnig the following command

```
cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
```

**Step 2:** Check if the plugin is listed in the config.xml and that you have set the required permissions for push notifications.

For Android

```
<config-file parent="/manifest" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
</config-file>
```

For iOS

```
<config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSAppTransportSecurity">
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</config-file>
<config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSCameraUsageDescription">
    <string>Allow the app to access the camera.</string>
</config-file>
<config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSMicrophoneUsageDescription">
    <string>Allow the app to access the microphone.</string>
</config-file>
<config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
    <string>Allow the app to access the photo library.</string>
</config-file>
<config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSUserNotificationTypes">
    <integer>7</integer>
</config-file>
```